# Make multiple page Logins with WebDriver Selenium using Groovy and Spring Boot

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, geb

i'm using Geb Selenium with Phantomjs Driver, realy using a RemoteWebDriver for interact with a web page using the phantomjs running over a console, i'm using also Spring boot so i call my Groovy Geb scripts from a REST method, what i want is to, for example, running scripts that login two different users asynchronously and make some work in their accounts, but when i run my code is like the first loged user is used over the second, i check in my code if the user is loged then go to his account, is like Selenium or Phantomjs uses an only one Browser for all my request so when i do a request for login and then make another one the first login is presents, is there a way for run my request in an isolated browser or driver in my case, or maybe is because some kind of cookies?

this is the code where i do my login using Groovy geb (called from a REST method in Spring):

```
 public void test_make_login(String login, String password){
    def String imgUrl = null
    Browser.drive {
        to MyPage

        makeLogin(login,password){
            println page
            imgUrl = profileThumbnail.attr("src")
        }{
            imgUrl = "none"
        }

        println imgUrl
    }
}
```

I'm using Angular $resource for make my REST requests, in my program i want to get the profile loged picture of each user but all users haves the first loged accound picture.

Comment: Tried `clearCookies()` before `close()`?

Comment: that works in a synchronous enviroment but i'm using angular $resource for call my REST method so there can be two or more calls to that code, now i realized that the behavior can be tricky when two threads are calling the same page, is like to users trying to make clicks at the same time, how can i use a Browser for each thread? when i say threads i'm thinking about the REST method called by each angular $resource call